# Register existing user on another site in a multisite network?

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I've got a multisite installation that contains users that will need access to more than one of the sites.

If a user already has access to one site, I'd like them to easily be able to sign up, using their existing username/password, for another site in the multisite installation.

How is this done?

Comment: Hello Dave. On WordPress, all the sites on a network use a single user table, and by default, they can easily login into another site on the network, except if this behavior has been changed.

Comment: Here's the stream: On a multisite network, if a user is logged in on one site, then they are automatically logged in into every other site on the network, unless if this default behavior has altered.

Comment: Right but the problem is they have no access to the other sites on the network.  I'd like them to be able to somehow register to get subscriber-level access.

Comment: They don't have to register again. Why not hook into the https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register action that is called whenever a new user is registered and do necessary stuff, like adding them to the other sites on the network

Comment: I know they don't have to register again... it's just I'd like a way for them to request a subscriber role on certain other sites in the network. I was _hoping_ there was a plugin ready-to-use to do that, I'll write it myself if I really have to.

Comment: Alright, I get it. That'll be fine.

Comment: What role should they have on other sites?

Comment: Subscriber would be fine.